# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here

Tags: java, oracle, jdbctemplate

I'm getting an error with SQL, but when I run the same INSERT in SQL Developer it works.

Here is the code:

```
// insert
String sql = "INSERT INTO matches (id, status, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_goals, away_goals) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

System.out.println( match.getId() ); // 233028
System.out.println( match.getStatus() ); // FINISHED
System.out.println( match.getHomeTeam().getId() ); // 66
System.out.println( match.getAwayTeam().getId() ); // 338
System.out.println( match.getHomeGoals() ); // 2 
System.out.println( match.getAwayGoals() ); // 1

jdbcTemplate.update(
    sql, 
    match.getId(),
    match.getStatus(),
    match.getHomeTeam().getId(),
    match.getAwayTeam().getId(),
    match.getHomeGoals(),
    match.getAwayGoals()
);
```

Here is the error in full:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO matches (id, status, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_goals, away_goals) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here
```

Here is the output from `SQL> DESCRIBE matches` :

```
Name         Null?    Type         
------------ -------- ------------ 
ID           NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
STATUS                VARCHAR2(16) 
HOME_TEAM_ID          NUMBER(6)    
AWAY_TEAM_ID          NUMBER(6)    
HOME_GOALS            NUMBER(2)    
AWAY_GOALS            NUMBER(2)
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: IDK anything about Spring, but in Hibernate, you can enable sql trace to see the exact sql being sent to the database.  Maybe there is something similar in spring?

Comment: Your error says `INSERT INTO matches (id, status, home_team_id, ...` but your example says `INSERT INTO matches (status, home_team_id, ...` (notice the `id` column missing). Are you sure you are showing the right example?

Comment: You might also get a similar error if your actual INSERT statement contains reserved/key words as table or column names, so please check that you're sharing the actual query you're using.

Comment: Sorry! Yes, I did notice that just before I posted this that I'd missed out "id" column. Then I added it hoping it had fixed it, but same error. I mistakenly didn't update the above to reflect the current code. Anyway, I'd updated my post now. Same error though.

Comment: If that Oracle instance has [Oracle Text](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#g1016054) features enabled, the table name `MATCHES` could be problematic because that is a keyword/operator you can use in queries. I'd suggest renaming the table slightly if possible and trying again.

Comment: Unless you already renamed the table, you could also try to escape the table name with double quotes (easier to try, sorry I didn't think of that first): `String sql = "INSERT INTO \"MATCHES\" (id, status, home_team_id, away_team_id, home_goals, away_goals) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";`

Comment: Which `jdbcTemplate.update()` method are you using? I just looked at the docs and I don't see one that matches your arguments

Comment: `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` ...
`public int update(String sql, Object... args) throws DataAccessException`